# When to use indefinite article "a(n)" when referring to a person with an adjective?

Tags: indefinite-articles, reference

I'm not a native English speaker. From time to time I see the following structure when referring to a person:

... a(n) [adjective] [person's name] ...

example:

> "Meanwhile, **an** increasingly sadistic Henry begins focusing his attention..."
>
> / Wikipedia: It (novel) /

I'm pretty sure that the following is correct as well:

> "Meanwhile, **the** increasingly sadistic Henry begins focusing his attention..."

What's the difference between these?

Comment: ***an** increasingly sadistic Henry* could be seen as implying Henry has many facets to his personality, some of which may not be "sadistic" at all, let alone increasingly so. From this perspective, ***the** increasingly sadistic Henry* tends to imply his character is relatively "fixed" insofar as he's always been sadistic (it's just that in the specific context, he's becoming even more sadistic that he was earlier). But this is a fine distinction that won't always be either intended or understood.

Answer (score -1):

Using an indefinite article implies that the explanation is an example.  The definite article implies we are talking about a specific instance.